# HTML images conditional downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have something like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="bigimage_1.jpg" />
    <img src="bigimage_2.jpg" />
    <img src="bigimage_3.jpg" />
    ...
    <img src="bigimage_n.jpg" />
</div>
```

The div should only be shown if the width of the viewport is greater than 300px.

Since the images are very large, I dont want them to be downloaded when the width is lower than 300px. But when the width is greater than 300px I need to start downloading them as soon as possible.

Also, this should work on a lot of browsers on a lot of devices so I want to make it as robust as possible.

I was thinking in using https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL and call the jail function on $(document).ready, but I don't know if there is a better solution.
Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for recommendations for. Are you soliciting a solution for conditional loading of images based on the width of the viewport? Are you asking us to review a solution you're proposing?

Comment: soliciting a solution for conditional downloading of images based on some condition

Comment: The only way to not download it is to not include it in the dom unless you want it downlaoded. Removing the element from the dom won't stop the browser from downloading it.

Comment: The JAIL solution still makes an http request, even if the image it retrieves is only a small .gif. Better would be to use a non-image element with a data attribute that you then use to grab asynchronously. Couple this with the noscript used in JAIL and it should work.

Comment: @pomber Take a look at this link http://24ways.org/2011/conditional-loading-for-responsive-designs/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a look at [Scott Jehl's picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) solution. It takes a somewhat similar approach to JAIL in terms of implementing a no-js solution using the noscript tag to provide the fallback image, but it avoids the initial http request made for the placeholder .gif.

Comment: Picturefill is pretty cool. If you need load events for the images, you can also try my jquery.pikshur plugin: https://github.com/geekytime/jquery.pikshur

Answer (score 0):

You can try use CSS @media (min-width: 300px) { … }

Comment: media queries don't work in terms of loading images conditionally - they only work with specifying different background images

Answer (score 0):

Put a `$(document).ready` function, test the viewport (or the render area available for the image, accounting for body and other element's margin, paddings, etc) width with a conditional statement, and call the jail function if it passes.

You could place a width-greedy-zero height (with css) empty element where the images are supposed to be loaded, and test how much width it can get by selecting him via jquery. If its width is greater than 300, call the JAIL.